# unable to update timestamp in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the query I am using

```
update table_x set is_resolved = true and updated_on='2015-02-06 13:51:04.980294' 
where ps='XXX' and pi='YYY' and is_resolved is false and activity_type='ZZZ'
```

Result on running update is:

`"Query returned successfully: one row affected, 22 ms execution time."`

When I do

```
select * from table_x where where ps='XXX' and pi='YYY'  and activity_type='ZZZ'
```

I still see that `is_resolved` or `updated_on` values are not changed

Comment: Maybe you meant:  `UPDATE table_x set is_resolved = true , updated_on='2015-02-06 13:51:04.980294' where ps='XXX' and pi='YYY' and is_resolved is false and activity_type='ZZZ'`

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you I see what I did there